# SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services: "Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

When I run a report on SSRS reporting services to fetch 600000 row.. I get a error "Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown".

I read so many blog's for solving this issue but still I can't to solve it.

I am working on 32 bit OS(window server 2008) and SQL Server 2008 R2 32 bit.

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the physical RAM available on the box?.What are the other process running at the background? Do you have baseline data handy? Also just to add up, there are limited benefits of using 32 bit in scenarios where memory is needed compared to 64 bit, which broader the usage of memory.

Comment: I typically run across this when the client simply can't load up all the data being returned on SSRS or the built in SQL Server 'reports' where it generates a nice report instead of just returning the raw data.  Can you just return the raw data from the same client?  If not, can you break down the data being returned or run it from another machine?  It could just be the server side though.

Comment: Are you sure you need a report with 600,000 rows? I wouldn't want to read it. If you are using this as a data extract, don't. If the report is summarising this data or graphing it, summarise it in the SQL query.

Comment: I am using 4 GB RAM on 32 bit..and only one ManagerApp(.net Application) is running.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the server to a 64 bit version of Windows, and a 64 bit version of SQL Server *might* help.

However, what are you doing with a report with 600,000 rows?  If you are using this to export data, you should use SSIS or some other tool designed for the job.  If you are summarizing the data inside the report, re-write the source query to summary the data at the server prior to it arriving at the SSRS instance.